# mouse enter event is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to hide a `div` on mouse enter on body, it is not working properly, the `div` I am trying to hide, will hide and comes again. Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yGUC8/)

Here is my code:

JS:

```
$(document).mouseenter(function() {
    $('.jadu').hide(10);
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $('.jadu').show(10);
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jadu"></div>
```

CSS:

```
*{padding:0px;margin:0px;}
.jadu{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#555;
    opacity:0.8;
    display:block;
    z-index:3;
}
body{
    background:red;
}
```

this is fiddle link: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yGUC8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the `mouseleave` event.

```
$(document).mouseenter(function() {
    $('.jadu').hide(10);
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.jadu').show(10);
  });
```

#### JS Fiddle

When you use `mouseout` on an element and there is a child in it (`document > .jadu`) the mouseout event is triggered when you hover the `.jadu` element (child).

Using `mouseleave`, this event won't be triggered when you hover a child of `document`.

Comment: working like a charm :) :).. could you please help me with the differences between `mouseout` and `mouseleave`

Answer (score 1):

See the fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/UaJZr/

```
$(document).mouseenter(function() {
  $('.jadu').hide(10);
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $('.jadu').show(10);
});
```

If the matched elements have no child element, both mouseout() and mouseleave() events are work exactly same.

If the matched elements have child element, both mouseout() and mouseleave() events are work different in the way of “event bubbling”.

You can see this page which explains clearly -> [Difference between mouseout()  and mouseleave()](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseleave event. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yGUC8/2/)

```
$(document).mouseenter(function() {
    $('.jadu').hide(10);
  });
$(document).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.jadu').show(10);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yGUC8/3/)

```
/* Do not use equal time in hide and show: */

$(document).mouseenter(function() {
    $('.jadu').hide(100);
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $('.jadu').show();
  });
```